# failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html

Tags: kubernetes, containers, containerd, harbor

I try pull image in K8s from my private registry

But the container describe show

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  14s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/k8m-deploy-574c7f7f9f-t59hm to w02
  Normal   BackOff    14s               kubelet            Back-off pulling image "plzharbor.com/k8mtest/k8m:v1.0"
  Warning  Failed     14s               kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    3s (x2 over 14s)  kubelet            Pulling image "plzharbor.com/k8mtest/k8m:v1.0"
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 14s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "plzharbor.com/k8mtest/k8m:v1.0": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "plzharbor.com/k8mtest/k8m:v1.0": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:9e0ca048375f6acc79b1fb61008d69b89655b4d33efaa1f217a4d7c3b2c69a01: not found
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 14s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

All Node : Ubuntu 20, Contianerd v1.6.17

Docker Node : Docker v23.0.1, Harbor v2.5.5

K8s Node : K8s v1.26.1

---

I first edit hosts in all node

```
vim /etc/hosts
192.168.100.142 plzharbor.com
```

and than creat CA for Docker Node and publish

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -sha512 -days 3650 \
 -subj "/C=CN/ST=Beijing/L=Beijing/O=example/OU=Personal/CN=plzharbor.com" \
 -key ca.key \
 -out ca.crt

openssl genrsa -out plzharbor.com.key 4096

openssl req -sha512 -new \
    -subj "/C=CN/ST=Beijing/L=Beijing/O=example/OU=Personal/CN=plzharbor.com" \
    -key plzharbor.com.key \
    -out plzharbor.com.csr

cat > v3.ext <<-EOF
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1=plzharbor.com
DNS.2=plzharbor
EOF

openssl x509 -req -sha512 -days 3650 \
    -extfile v3.ext \
    -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial \
    -in plzharbor.com.csr \
    -out plzharbor.com.crt

openssl x509 -inform PEM -in plzharbor.com.crt -out plzharbor.com.cert
```

edit harbor.yml to set path for `plzharbor.com.crt`, `plzharbor.com.key`

```
hostname: plzharbor.com
http:
  port: 80
https:
  port: 443
  # The path of cert and key files for nginx
  certificate: /data/cert/plzharbor.com.crt
  private_key: /data/cert/plzharbor.com.key
```

cpoy  `ca.crt`,  `plzharbor.com.cert`, `plzharbor.com.key` to /etc/docker/certs.d/plzharbor.com/

restart docker and run `./prepare ./install.sh`

**its worked docker login plzharbor.com**

and than i push a image which tag is plzharbor.com/k8mtest/k8m:v1.0, its also worked

this image is a simple go server

```
FROM golang:1.20.1 as build

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64 \
    GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn/,direct

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .

FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /app/resource /resource
COPY --from=build /app/main main
EXPOSE 8181
CMD ["./main"]
```

i publish CA to every node at `/etc/containerd/certs.d/plzharbor.com/`, edit containerd config in every node and restart contianerd

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."plzharbor.com"]
          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."plzharbor.com".tls]
            insecure_skip_verify = false
            ca_file = "/etc/containerd/certs.d/plzharbor.com/ca.crt"
            cert_file = "/etc/containerd/certs.d/plzharbor.com/plzharbor.com.crt"
            key_file = "/etc/containerd/certs.d/plzharbor.com/plzharbor.com.key"
          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."plzharbor.com".auth]
            username = "admin"
            password = "Harbor12345"
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
        endpoint = ["https://registry.aliyuncs.com", "https://hub-mirror.c.163.com/"]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."plzharbor.com"]
        endpoint = ["https://plzharbor.com/"]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".x509_key_pair_streaming]
      tls_cert_file = ""
      tls_key_file = ""
```

last I use a yml try to create a deploy, but fail

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry plz\
  --docker-server=plzharbor.com \
  --docker-username=admin \
  --docker-password=Harbor12345
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8m-deploy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8m
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8m
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: plzharbor.com/k8mtest/k8m:v1.0
          name: k8m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8181
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: plz
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: svc-k8m
  name: svc-k8m
spec:
  selector:
    app: k8m
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8181
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8181
      nodePort: 30801
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been resolved，and the main reason is the trust of CA among nodes，all CA needs to be put in the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ of the nodes and trust it, and no need to modify the containerd's toml confiuration